# Plot two lines on same month with different dates with Base-unit :month

Tags: kendo-ui

I am developing a chart on Kendo-UI, where we need to plot a vertical line w.r.t dates available on the x-axis. The challenge, that I am facing is my x-axis contains BaseUnit: months. when I am plotting bands w.r.t two different dates in the same month, the system generates vertical line but captures a complete month section rather than plotting two different lines in the same month.

Sample Code:

```js
var DateRange = [];
        var PlotData = [];
        var AllData = [];
        function BindDates() {
            for (var startmonth = 01; startmonth <= 12; startmonth++) {


                for (var startday = 01; startday <= 30; startday++) {

                    DateRange.push(new Date("2019/" + startmonth + "/" + startday));
                    AllData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * startday) * new Date().getMilliseconds()));
                }
                for (var Initial = 1; Initial <= 3; Initial++) {
                    var data = null;
                    if (Initial == 1) {
                       data = { from: new Date("2019/02/03"), to: new Date("2019/02/03"), color: "red", width: 0.1 };

                    }
                    else if (Initial == 2) {
                        data = { from: new Date("2019/05/03"), to: new Date("2019/05/03"), color: "green", width: 0.1 };
                    }
                    else if (Initial == 3) {
                        data = { from: new Date("2019/06/03"), to: new Date("2019/06/03"), color: "black", width: 0.1 };
                    }
                    PlotData.push(data);
                }
            }

            createChart(DateRange, AllData, PlotData);
        }
        function createChart(datesss, alldata, PlotData) {

            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Chart Title"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "area",
                    area: {
                        line: {
                            style: "smooth"
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [

                    {
                        name: "Late",
                        color: "orange",
                        data: alldata  

                    }, {
                        type: "line",
                        dashType: "dashDot",
                        name: "Est DT",
                        color: "grey",
                        data: alldata 
                    },
                    {
                        name: "On time",
                        color: "blue",
                        data: alldata 
                    }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: -10
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    type: "date",
                    categories: datesss,
                    baseUnit: "months",
                    labels: {
                        dateFormats: {
                            months: "MMM-yy"
                        }
                    },
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        rotation: "auto",

                    },
                    plotBands: PlotData

                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
        }
        
        BindDates();
$(document).ready(function () {
        BindDates();
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```

Comment: I shared source code

Comment: Had you checked the code